# Expression for treating people for punishment/demotion/embarrassment?

Tags: expressions

When a boss does not like someone, and gives them a meaningless job to embarrass them. Is there a expression for such treatment, e.g. put in a dog house?

Comment: [Constructive dismissal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_dismissal)?

Answer (score 1):

**put to shame**

> To cause to feel shame. [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=put%20to%20shame), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/put-to-shame#:%7E:text=put%20to%20shame%20in%20American,full%20dictionary%20entry%20for%20shame)

---

> The general meaning "**put to shame**" in the sense of "**embarrass**",
> "**humiliate**" is indicated, for example, in Luke 13:17, I Cor. 11:22;
> ... [Stephen Renn; *Expository Dictionary of Bible Words*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Expository_Dictionary_of_Bible_Words/k8GgQqUxPgMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22put%20to%20shame%22%20embarrassed&pg=PA66&printsec=frontcover) (2005)

> Chinese intellectuals during this time were put to work in rural
> areas, toiling away at **demeaning jobs** that required physical
> labour. Former mayors and provincial officials were reported to have
> been **put to shame**, forced to wear dunce caps and their faces
> smeared with ink. Landowners had their hair cropped and were forced to
> bow before crowds. [David Abdulai; *Chinese Investment in Africa*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Chinese_Investment_in_Africa/nz8lDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22put%20to%20shame%22%20demeaning%20job&pg=PA11&printsec=frontcover)
> (2016)

> The Bible provides ample proof to show that if a believer sins and is
> unfaithful, he can be **put to shame** and receive a **punishment** in the
> coming kingdom. [The Collected Works of Witness Lee, 1932-1949, Vol.
> 1](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Collected_Works_of_Witness_Lee_1932/hmrIDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22put%20to%20shame%22%20punishment&pg=PT251&printsec=frontcover)